# What happens with Process Builder runtime errors?

Tags: process-builder, error

When happens when a process with multiple steps encounters a runtime error?  Does it stop processing at its current step or does it stop processing the current step and move to the next?

Salesforce tells us the user gets an error message, but they don't specify what happens in the process:

[Link to Salesforce Process documentation:](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.process_troubleshoot_runtime.htm&type=5)

I suspect the process stops, but I'd like to know for sure.  If I get time, I'll rig up a test case.  I'm hoping someone knows the answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process stops and the transaction fails; everything up to the last save point is rolled back (typically, the entire transaction, but things like `allOrNone=false` will allow a retry, minus any records which errored). Note that in a bulk operation, all instances of the process are allowed to attempt the same step to allow individual success/failure, but the next steps won't be evaluated in either scenario.